# mySQL prepend text to column if not null

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, concatenation

I just did a mass import of 200,000 items into the database, but forgot to add the directories under the image column. Is there a way to mass update the column and prepend the images directory? This is what I've been trying, but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE wp_store_locator SET sl_image = CONCAT(  'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/', sl_image ) WHERE sl_image != NULL
```

This runs successfully, but doesn't alter the `sl_image` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IS` operator when comparing with `null`

```
UPDATE wp_store_locator 
SET sl_image = CONCAT('http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/', sl_image ) 
WHERE sl_image is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not a value - it's the lack thereof. Thus, it cannot be tested with the `=` or `!=` operators, but needs to be checked with the `is` operator:

```
UPDATE wp_store_locator 
SET   sl_image = CONCAT('http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/',
                        sl_image ) 
WHERE sl_image IS NOT NULL
```